# Creating a php file for translating the content dynamically

Tags: php, mysql, language-translation

I have a database that has around 700 terms. I would just like to write a single php file called internationalize that would check the mysql database and return the proper translation. All the PHP variables have been setup and there is view that contains the translation of all the languages. There are about 11 languages. I have looked in a lot of places, but there isn't one that fits my situation. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION))
{
    session_start();
}

if (isset($setup))
{
    $lang=$_SESSION['setupLang'];
}
elseif (isset($_SESSION['lang']))
{
    $lang=$_SESSION['lang'];
}
else
{
require("fetchMainConfig.php");
}

$lang_code = $lang; 
//file_dir contains the language codes for example: il,fr,pt,ge and so on
$sql = "SELECT file_dir FROM `hydroserver_translation`.`language_file_dir`";
if($lang_code = $sql){
    // What should go in here??? What is the best way to
    // dynamically translate the database?
}
```

I am also attaching a copy of the database view. I plan to write the code is such a way that if there is no language translation the default translation is in english.

[image: User image]

Comment: Any reason you're not going with gettext and POT files?

Comment: What text do you want to translate? I don't understand what is the input.

Comment: Looks like the script assigns values to php variables depending on the language that is chosen. It seems that the script generates several variables that get its values from the database and are used in the rest of the script.

Comment: We want to give the user more flexibility when they translate. Since the database and the website contain several scientific variables, its better to allow the user to input the translated data. @A.L These are all the php variables that we are using to display information on the website. So we are basically translating the content on the entire webpage.

Comment: I think if you have values and translations you want to create a variable that can be accessed by `$value` for each value. You can write `$$database_result["value"] = translation`. This link explains how it works: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php
But this could also override important variables or functions in php, so I do not recommend this approach. It is better to use an array for that, also because storing and retrieving data from an array is easier.

Comment: 1. See normalization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I have done and it works. Thank you for your help!

```
<?php
//Connects to the database
$mysqlserver="servername";
$mysqlusername="langreader";
$mysqlpassword="readHSLlang@9";
$error=0;
$link=mysqli_connect($mysqlserver, $mysqlusername, $mysqlpassword) or $error=1;

$dbname = 'translation';
mysqli_select_db($link, $dbname) or $error=1;
if(!$error)
{//check which is the session language

$language = $lang_code;
//language file path
$file_path = "languages/" .$language. ".php";
//Check if file exists

$file_exists = file_exists($file_path);
if($file_exists){
// The file exists. Now just check when it was last time created.
$file_created_time =  filemtime($file_path);
$timezone = date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$current_time = time();
//Time lapse to check the difference between the current time and the last created time
$time_lapse = (abs($current_time-$file_created_time)/60/60);
//SQL statement to access the view from the database
$sql = "SELECT * FROM translation.translations_by_language";
$terms = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
//Will create a new file if it has been more than four hours
if($time_lapse >= '4.0'){
//Deleting the existing file to avoid any parsing errors
unlink($file_exists);
//Writing the new language_file
$lang_file= fopen("languages/" .$language. ".php","c+");
//Loops through the query and shows the translated terms 
//and english terms if there are no translations for the term
$new_file = "<?php" . "\n "; 
fwrite($lang_file, $new_file);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($terms)) {


        if ($row[$language] != "")
            fwrite($lang_file,$row['php_variable']. " = " . '"' . addslashes($row[$language]) . '"' . ";" . "\n ");
        else
            fwrite($lang_file,$row['php_variable']. " = " . '"' . addslashes($row['english_phrase']) . '"' . ";" . "\n ");
    }
    $last_line = "?>";
fwrite($lang_file, $last_line);
fclose($lang_file);
}   
}
else{
// Creating a new file if the file doesn't exist
$sql = "SELECT * FROM hydroserver_translation.translations_by_language";
$terms = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$lang_file= fopen("languages/" .$language. ".php","c+");
$new_file = "<?php" . "\n "; 
fwrite($lang_file, $new_file);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($terms)) {
print_r($row);
        if ($row[$language] != "")
//Provide the translation
            fwrite($lang_file,$row['php_variable']. " = " . '"' . addslashes($row[$language]) . '"' . ";" . "\n ");
//If translation doesn't exist, just use the english phrase
        else
            fwrite($lang_file,$row['php_variable']. " = " . '"' . addslashes($row['english_phrase']) . '"' . ";" . "\n ");
    }
    $last_line = "?>";
fwrite($lang_file, $last_line);
fclose($lang_file);
//New language file succesfully created!!!!
}
}
```